# InfluxDB on Windows Subsystem for Linux "cannot allocate memory"

Tags: influxdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Windows Subsystem for Linux running Ubuntu 16.04, I've installed InfluxDB 1.4.2 according to the [Influx documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/introduction/installation/).  I can't run it as a service or with systemctl, probably because WSL doesn't support that (see GitHub issues [994](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/994) and [1579](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1579)), so neither of these work:

```
$ sudo service influxdb start
influxdb: unrecognized service
$ sudo systemctl start influxdb
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

If I run `$ sudo influxd`, Influx starts, but then crashes with the message

```
run: open server: open tsdb store: cannot allocate memory
```

**How do I fix the "cannot allocate memory" error?**

Comment: I uninstalled and deleted my database (`$ sudo apt-get purge influxdb; sudo rm -rf /var/lib/influxdb`), then reinstalled, and now it works, but I'd love to know what was going wrong in the first place.

Comment: It means the DB would need more memory than what is available to use. How that is handled by WSL is anyone's guess. You are better off running on actual Linux, even virtualised.

Answer (score 3):

On Win10 Spring 2018 Update, I ran the following:

```
sudo apt install influxdb influxdb-client -y
```

Installed fine.

As per the docs …
[image]

… started the service using:

```
sudo service influxdb start
```

Started fine:
[image]

Let's connect, examine and create a database:
[image]

Please let me know if I've done anything wrong here to repro, otherwise, looks like this issue has been resolved.

Comment: This method works on Win11 with WSL2 and Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem when installing in WSL but `systemd` was installed. When installing the `influxdb` package it registered a systemd unit so I was unable to start it using init.d. I solved this using [this guide](https://caffinc.github.io/2015/12/influxdb-service-ubuntu/). Instead of the dead link to the init.sh script i searched for an older version and found [this](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/1.8/scripts/init.sh).

## Steps to get InfluxDB working in WSL (at least when systemd is installed):

1. Install influxdb using `sudo apt install influxdb`
2. Copy the content of [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/influxdata/influxdb/1.8/scripts/init.sh) into a new file at location `/etc/init.d/influxdb`
3. You can now start influxdb using `sudo service influxdb start`.

For me it showed an error message while starting but it still started correctly.

Comment: I didn't try to start it manually, but no init.d unit was created like in the question. Instead it created a symlink like you would need it with systemd.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (it doesn't start any process) :-/ Are you running WSL2?

Comment: I think I was running WSL2. Since this answer is a year old and the link in step 2 points to a specific version you could try [the most recent version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/influxdata/influxdb/master/scripts/init.sh) of the file instead.